# Floating-point issue with an example of Gaussian elimination in Burden & Faires

Tags: floating-point, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I am reading Section 6.2, Page 360 of Burden & Faires, 9th edition. It contains an example which aims at illustrating the numerical instability of Gaussian elimination without row interchanges (i.e., without any pivoting). The floating point is **decimal** and the precision is **four** as can be seen in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0qoi.png)

The augmented matrix [A b] is as follows

```
[ 0.003000  5914   59.17
  5.291    -6.130  46.78].
```

Without row interchanges, the 'large' multiplier is m_21 = 1764. Denoting the equation corresponding with row 1 as E1 and using fl(.) to denote an operation in floating-point arithmetic, we then have

```
fl(m_21 * E1) = [5.292  104300  104400].
```

Note that 104300 and 104400 above have no issues with precision 4, i.e. they are exactly representable in this system thanks to the scientific notation 1.043 x 10^5 and 1.044 x 10^5. But, then I get

```
fl(E2 - m_21 * E1) = [fl(5.291 - 5.292)  fl(-6.130 - 104300)  fl(46.78 - 104400)] = 
                   = [- 0.001000   -104300  -104400].
```

What's striking here is that the first entry is `10^(-3)` and I don't see any reason **why it is replaced with zero in the textbook**! As far as I understand, `**10^(-3)` is exactly representable** in any reasonable decimal floating-point system with precision four. In other words, I don't see how the authors claimed to have transformed the coefficient matrix to upper-triangular. Is this a mistake or a bad choice of example in the textbook or am I missing something here? Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: When working on a particular column with Gaussian elimination, the goal is to eliminate entries in the column being worked on other than the one chosen to keep. Algebraically (disregarding floating-point rounding), the subtraction must yield zero: b−aq is exactly zero when q has been set to b/a. So, when working on a row, the software is written to set the working column entry to zero rather than to calculate it. The other columns are then calculated with floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: in fact, the entries are not even set to zero, as they will never be used again. [In case of LU decomposition, they are even overwritten with the elimination coefficients.]